# Update very nested document in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How can I update `array1.array2.status`, given the following Schema?

```
var SomeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    status: Boolean, 
    array1: [{
        array2[{
            status: boolean
        }]
    }]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it would be nice to reorganize your Schema into SubSchema like this :

```
var valueItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
    status: Boolean
});

var subItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
    array2: [valueItemSchema]
});

/*
//or this if you dont want _id in your nested documents

var valueItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    status: Boolean
}, {
    _id: false
});

var subItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    array2: [valueItemSchema]
}, {
    _id: false
});
*/

var itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    status: Boolean,
    array1: [subItemSchema]
});

var valueItem = db.model('ValueItem', valueItemSchema);
var SubItem = db.model('SubItem', subItemSchema);
var Item = db.model('Item', itemSchema);

//create a new item
var myItem = new Item({
    status: true,
    array1: new SubItem({
        _id: 0,
        array2: [new valueItem({
            _id: 0,
            "status": true
        }), new valueItem({
            _id: 1,
            "status": false
        }), new valueItem({
            _id: 2,
            "status": true
        })]
    })
});
```

Then, you can update an element of your `array2` by `_id` :

```
Item.findOne({
    status: true
}).exec(
    function(err, result) {
        result.array1.id(0).array2.id(0).status=false;
        result.save(function(err) {
            console.log(result)
        });
    }
);
```

Or if you dont want any `_id` in your subdocuments update by index :

```
Item.findOne({
    status: true
}).exec(
    function(err, result) {

        result.array1[0].array2[0].status=false;
        result.save(function(err) {
            console.log(result)
        });
    }
);
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/7b845527ee8f80a628aaf529fed50fe6) is a full demo